# read a file inside of a setup package

Tags: file, wix, windows-installer, embed

I have a file which I want to use during install. It contains some SQL. This file is not used by the installed application itself, so I don't want it to be installed to the client machine, I want it to be a part of the setup package like my custom action DLLs that I specify using Binary element. But how do I read that file if I embed it into the setup package? Are there any built-in WiX/DTF functions for that? Or maybe I should embed that file in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've discovered for myself - create a Properties file for the WiX custom actions library and add all SQL there. **No additional actions should be done** for the SQL to be available in the custom actions! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something along the following lines:

- use the `<binary>` element to include
  the file as a stream in the Binary
  table of your package.
- Stream the
  file out of the binary table to a
  temp file in an immediate custom
  action, and store the location of the
  temp file in a property, e.g.
  CleanupSQLFile
- Do whatever it is
  you need to do with the file
- Clean up
  the file once you are done with it. If you need to clean up the file as part of a deferred or commit operation then you will need to use a Action called CleanupSQLFile and read in the file location from the CustomActionData property. The Property and CustomAction **must** have the same name

There's an [example of streaming a file from the binary table](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/ca.htm) on InstallSite.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. You can deploy that file at some location and then easily read, edit, execute from that location